# Python divide each integer in line from text file

Tags: python, integer, divide

I have the following code:

```
total = 49971
with open("user1_wordcount.txt",'r') as f:
     for line in f:
         lines = line.split()
         count = lines([1])
         mean = count/total
print(mean)
```

The text file is made up of lines in the format:

```
Google 348
Amazon 120
.
.
.
```

So i need to divide each number by 49971, and the output to look something like:

```
Google 0.00696404
.
.
.
```

etc.

Comment: If you wish, you can shorten your code by replacing three lines by `mean = float(line.split()[1])/total`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
total = 49971
with open("user1_wordcount.txt",'r') as f:
     for line in f:
         company_name, count = line.rstrip().split()
         print( company_name, float(count)/total)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `count = lines[1]` instead of `count = lines([1])` to access element of a list. You also need to use `float()` to convert it.

Comment: You also need to convert it to `float` before using division.